# Error in AngularJS: Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-components

I have the following code in my template:

```
<my-tasks tasks="$ctrl.tasks | filter: {state: 'proposed'}"></my-tasks>
<my-tasks tasks="$ctrl.tasks | filter: {state: 'draft'}"></my-tasks>
```

I have a component that I am attempting to pass filtered data to for two instances of that component.

I keep receiving the following error in the console:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations
```

Below is my component code:

```
class MyTasksController {
    constructor() {
    }
}

MyTasksController.$inject = [];

export const myTasksComponent = {
    template: require('./my-tasks.html'),
    controller: MyTasksController,
    bindings: {
        id: '<',
        tasks: '<'
    }
};
```

Comment: Please add `myTask` directive codes into question.

Comment: This may be because something is called in an endless loop, please share your myTask directive code.

Comment: I've updated the question with my component code.